# asp.net menu with slider

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, menu, jquery-ui-slider

I am using the asp.net menu control but I need to add a slider to it so if the menu control grows outside the visible page then this restricts it and uses a jquery slider to view the other options hidden.  I have tried Jcarousel and now this one but have been able to implement this correctly.  2 things happen:

1. items are hidden and no matter what i click on it doesn't show them.
2. submenu doesn't appear anymore.

Any help or guidance to a better plugin that i can use i would really appreciate it.

```
    <link href="css/jquery.thumbnailScroller.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Add jQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jquery ui custom build (for animation easing) -->
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        /* jQuery.noConflict() for using the plugin along with other libraries.
        You can remove it if you won't use other libraries (e.g. prototype, scriptaculous etc.) or
        if you include jQuery before other libraries in yourdocument's head tag.
        [more info: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries] */
        /* calling thumbnailScroller function with options as parameters */
        (function ($) {

            window.onload = function () {

                $("#tS2").thumbnailScroller({
                    scrollerType: "clickButtons",
                    scrollerOrientation: "horizontal",
                    scrollSpeed: 2,
                    scrollEasing: "easeOutCirc",
                    scrollEasingAmount: 600,
                    acceleration: 4,
                    scrollSpeed: 800,
                    noScrollCenterSpace: 10,
                    autoScrolling: 0,
                    autoScrollingSpeed: 2000,
                    autoScrollingEasing: "easeInOutQuad",
                    autoScrollingDelay: 500
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
    <!-- thumbnailScroller script -->
    <script src="js/jquery.thumbnailScroller.js"></script>


    <div id="tS2" class="jThumbnailScroller">
        <div class="jTscrollerContainer">
            <div class="jTscroller">    
                <asp:Menu ID="navigation" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" CssClass="topmenu" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="20" 
                    IncludeStyleBlock="false">
                   <DynamicSelectedStyle />
                    <DynamicMenuItemStyle />
                    <DynamicHoverStyle  />
                    <DynamicMenuStyle   />
                    <StaticMenuItemStyle  />
                    <StaticSelectedStyle />
                    <StaticHoverStyle  />
                </asp:Menu>
            </div>
       </div>
       <a href="#" class="jTscrollerPrevButton"></a>
       <a href="#" class="jTscrollerNextButton"></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try out this kind of navigation design on a tablet or smartphone. You may want to reconsider your design.

Comment: its not meant for tablet or mobil whrn we get to that it will have a completely different layout

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the postfixed `()` on your anonymous wrapper function, so the `window.onload` block won't ever execute.

Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: thats the code i got from the plugin and the weird thin is i dont get an error bc there is non the menu items that dont fit are just tkssed on a second line

Comment: *dont fit just passed onto a second line